# ghostinspector(phantomjs) running from jenkins and seeing result in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, ui-automation

I am using ghostinspector to record and run tests. I have also seen API integration.

Is there a way I can create a build and when I trigger this build, it runs test on ghostinspector. (I am able to do this using custom build command in jenkins which makes curl request)

In additional to triggering build I would like to see result in jenkins as well. does ghostinspector or phantomjs test script returns result in TAP format or any other format which jenkins can show as test results

Comment: It would seem so but you need to offer more information for a better answer https://ghostinspector.com/docs/integration/jenkins/

Comment: I have seen that link. It was to trigger build. Looks like showing result is currently not supported. Is there a way I can write myself some code to show results on jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work for Ghost Inspector.

We now offer the ability to download results from your test suite [in XUnit format via our API](https://ghostinspector.com/docs/api/suite-results/#xunit) that you should be able to [use in Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) to report on your suite status.

Hope that helps.